# (Bug) Elasticloadbalancer cant find ACM certificates with arn cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-cloudformation

In cloudformation I added two listeners to my load balancer. (HTTP & HTTPS)
When I try to add a certificate owned by Amazon in cloudformation it can't find the certificate in any way. I first tried to use a self-signed certificate which was not working anywhere also in the Amazon GUI. So I decided to add a Amazon managed certificate as alternative which could be found in the GUI of the loadbalancer.

But when I use ACM certificates in cloudformation it's always failing to import via ARN. 
The following error always popping up during the Cloudformation build: Certificate could not be found. 
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm currently using this loadbalancer: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer

Hopefully I can get a useful answer for this of error.

Answer (score 1):

Could you share the relevant cloudformation snippet? What's the status of the certificate in the ACM? Make sure it's `Issued`.

Meanwhile, sharing the working cloudformation template snippet.

I take Load Balancer Certificate ARN as an input parameter:

```
  LoadBalancerCertificateARN:
    Type: String
    Default: arn:aws:acm:ap-northeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:certificate/2d75cbe6-c1bb-286c-9cf4-34cc4f35b59c
    Description: Enter certificate ARN; Use ACM to create a certificate before creating this stack
```

And, here's my HTTPS listener snippet:

```
  PrivateALBHttpsListener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      Certificates:
      - CertificateArn: !Ref LoadBalancerCertificateARN
      DefaultActions:
      - TargetGroupArn: !Ref PrivateDefaultTargetGroup
        Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref PrivateALB
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have exactly the same... When I setup without HTTPS listener its working fine. After updating cloudformation with https listener its working now. Its seems like its a bug in cloudformation.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you. Is it working now just by retying?

Comment: Nope... First I added the whole configuration without HTTPS listener. After adding that configuration I added the HTTPS configuration.

Comment: CloudFormation is very unhelpful in this sense, as is the AWS console - CloudFormation says the certificate could not be found rather than the certificate is expired and the console doesn't call it out either.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand CloudFormation doesn't have ACM Certificate in a list of [AWS-Specific Parameter Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html), so there is no way to easily retrieve the list of available ACM public certificates to choose from.